# Browse excel workbook and open, then use workbook in code

Tags: vba, excel

I need a code to browse for a workbook on a server, the workbook needs to be opened and I need to make references to this workbook in my already existing code.

The code below works until I want to set Wb2 as the the workbook I opened using the code.

```
Sub openfile()

Dim strFilePath As String
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

strFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel
Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)

Set Wb2 = strFilePath
Wb2.Sheet3.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strFilePath` is just a string, not a workbook. You can get the workbook object from the `.Open` method:

```
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
```

Your next line will cause an error too since `Sheet3` is (I assume) an object in your workbook but not a property of the workbook class. Use

```
Wb2.Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate 'or whatever it's named
```

instead